# Symfony HTTP Client getting original request infos

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the [HTTPClient](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html) with Symfony 5.2

```php
$response = $myApi->request($method, $url, $options);
```

When a request fails, I'd like to get the detailed info about the original request, ie: the request headers.
`$response->getInfo()` does not return them (only the response headers).
My `$options` don't always have all that I need because some can come from the client config.

I need to log that somewhere in production, I saw [maintainers working on injecting a logger](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/30537) but didn't find more info about it.
After a quick check on the code, I can see that a logger can be set but it seems to log only the method and URI.

**How can I get the request info like headers or params/body ?**

[Github Issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40683) opened about this

Comment: Is there a `setLogger` method available on it?

Comment: Yes the `NativeHttpClient` is "Logger aware", I just checked, I don't know how to use that

Comment: There's probably a couple of ways. One is to bind a logger yaml, something I'm honestly not the best at. Another is instead of autowiring for `HttpClientInterface`, to just manually create an explicit one using `HttpClient::create()`. The last, which is what I would probably do, is keep the autowire for `HttpClientInterface` and also autowire a `LoggerInterface`. Then, test if your `HttpClientInterface` object is also an instance of `LoggerAwareInterface` which means that method exists. Unfortunately I don't have anything to code in front of me to write a sample.

Answer (score 3):

`$response->getInfo('debug')` contains the request headers [once they have been received](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40683#issuecomment-812996789) by the client.

```
dump($response->getInfo('debug'));
```

```
* Found bundle for host myapi: 0x7fe4c3f81580 [serially]
* Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host myapi
* Connected to myapi (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port xxxx (#0)
> POST /my/uri/ HTTP/1.1
Host: myapi:xxxx
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer e5vn9569-n76v9nd-v6n978-dv6n98
User-Agent: Symfony HttpClient/Curl
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 202

* upload completely sent off: 202 out of 202 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 8
< ETag: W/"8-M1u4Sc28uxk+zyXJvSTJaEkyIGw"
< Date: Tue, 06 Apr 2021 07:36:10 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host myapi left intact
```

Also [TraceableHttpClient](https://github.com/symfony/http-client/blob/v5.2.12/TraceableHttpClient.php) seems to be designed for detailed debuging

Comment: The link is dead :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick sample of one of the options that I posted in my comment:

```php
    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $client, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        if ($this->client instanceof LoggerAwareInterface) {
            $this->client->setLogger($logger);
        }
    }
```

You could also delay the `setLogger` to your use area, too.

Comment: Thx @Chris, however [`NativeHttpClient::request`](https://github.com/symfony/http-client/blob/5.x/NativeHttpClient.php#L180) doesn't seem to log anything else that the method and the URI

Comment: Hmm... I see that now, that sucks, and `NativeHttpClient` is final, too. Does `getInfo('debug')` on the response object have enough for you? I don't have time to test but [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/31641) seems like it might do the trick.

Comment: That's already merged into the version I'm using and this only contains the response headers

Comment: Actually it contains them once they are received by the client, I didn't wait enough